# Flutter Firestore permission denied despite the rule

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My rules are as follows:

```dart
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  

     match /classifiedAds/{uid}/{document=**} {
       allow read, create: if true; 
       allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == document.ownerId;  
    }
```

When I update a document, I get:

> I/flutter (32578): [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

This puzzles me because I've checked that the auth user did matches the `ownerId` property of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad. You can refer to the document property thru `resource.data.<property>`:

```dart
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  

     match /classifiedAds/{uid}/{document=**} {
       allow read, create: if true; 
       allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == request.data.ownerId;  
    }
```